# Add an image layer on hover

Tags: css, hover

I tried hard but could not find a solution...
I need, just using HTML/CSS to add an image layer over another image on mouseover.
The new layer should not replace the old one, only be summed (because it is semi-transparent).

My problem is: I have multiple different images and on mouseover the same layer should be added to them.

Is this possible?

I tried

```
<style type="text/css"> 
.image1 
{ 
opacity:1.0; 
filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */ 
}
.image1:hover 
{ 
background: url(http://bridgeditalia.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/over.png) no-repeat; 
} </style>
```

but not working :(

Comment: can we see the HTML? Is image1 an <img> or a link?

Comment: post your html or the link to your page

Comment: There is no image in your link . And isn't double quotes necessary in that parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the Z-INDEX on the hover and add some transition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option using a wrapping div and a pseudo element

[**JSfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6eW2D/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-200-200-9.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
<div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-200-200-4.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 25px;
    position: relative;
    }

.img-wrap:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-image: url(http://bridgeditalia.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/over.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity .5s ease;
}

.img-wrap:hover:after {
    opacity:1;
}

.img-wrap img {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your help... but the result is not exactly what I needed...because I need the images to be in the same div.. here is an example: http://bridgeditalia.it/lombardia/   your code and, on the right, the result that I need (but that was made with classic on mouseover html which is not good)

Comment: If you are re-using the same image over and over again it's poor coding to keep adding it in your HTML..especially if **it's just for styling**. You need to show us the HTML & CSS you do have rather than just give links to something someone else has done. You can always update your question.